# regex not capturing square braquets

Tags: javascript, regex

I am converting some wiki text to markdown. The wiki links are in format:

```
[[url|text]]
```

and I am having problems to find a regex to catch it.

The regex i am trying is `(\[\[(.*\|[^\]]*)\]\])` (live example: http://regex101.com/r/nW2zG7/1)

So in the following text:

```
Clicking this will echo out the code and the result in the [[http://getfirebug.com|Firebug]]     
debugging plugin for [[http://getfirefox.com|Firefox]]. 
If you don\'t have that plugin or Firefox, a similar 
console should be visible at the bottom of the page. This is a poor substitute for 
Firebug, so I highly recommend installing both [[http://getfirefox.com|Firefox]] and 
[[http://getfirebug.com|Firebug]] when viewing this tutorial.
```

It fails to catch the `text` of that link, and catches all this:

`http://getfirebug.com|Firebug]] debugging plugin for [[http://getfirefox.com|Firefox]]. If you don\'t have that plugin or Firefox, a similar console should be visible at the bottom of the page. This is a poor substitute for Firebug, so I highly recommend installing both [[http://getfirefox.com|Firefox]] and [[http://getfirebug.com|Firebug`

I supose I am doing something wrong here: `|[^\]]*)`

In the end I will run this regex in javascript like:

```
markdown = markdown.replace(/(\[\[(.*\|.*)\]\])/g, function(string, submatch1, submatch2){
    var parts = submatch2.split('|');
    return '[' + parts[1] + '](' + parts[0] + ')';
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the first `.*` in your regex which is greedy and matches all the character until the last `|` (not first). You should replace the `.*` with `[^\|]*` which is *all the characters except `|`*

That should match correctly `(\[\[([^\|]*\|[^\]]*)\]\])`

Answer (score 2):

```
(?:\[\[([^\[\]]*\|[^\]]*)\]\])
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/nW2zG7/2

Comment: The outer-most non-capturing group doesn't really seem to provide any value here. Am I overlooking a compelling reason for including it?

Comment: @TML just modified OP's regex.Yes de are not really needed

Comment: Perfectly reasonable - just wanted to make sure I hadn't missed something else. :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to [change the definition of greediness](https://eval.in/203075):

```
regex = /\[\[(.*?)\|(.*?)]]/g;

var markdown = str.replace(regex, function(string, m0, m1){
    return '[' + m1 + '](' + m0 + ')';
});
```

I like this because (IMO) it makes a much easier to read regex.

> If used immediately after any of the quantifiers *, +, ?, or {}, [the `?` metacharacter] makes
>   the quantifier non-greedy (matching the fewest possible characters),
>   as opposed to the default, which is greedy (matching as many
>   characters as possible). For example, applying /\d+/ to "123abc"
>   matches "123". But applying /\d+?/ to that same string matches only
>   the "1".

See [the MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-questionmark) for more details.